# moving files after brew doctor advise - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, homebrew

When running `brew doctor`, I get this message

```
Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/local/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

Can I safely move the `/opt/local/bin/pkg-config` file ?

Answer (score 0):

`/opt/local` is not used by the main system, but by MacPorts. Removing that `pkg-config` and installing the one from brew is the most sensible thing to do if you want to move to brew.

Comment: I thought `brew` used `/usr/local` no ?